# Accessing constants using strings / variables during runtime

Tags: go, constants

I am working on a cross-platform typing / key-press simulator. In this, I am trying to achieve a functionality as follows.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

const (
    VK_A = 5
    VK_S = 14
    VK_D = 25
)

func main() {
    // Suppose, I got user input "a", and based on this,
    // i want to print the value of VK_A
    var userInput string = "a"
    var constToSelect string = "VK_" + strings.ToUpper(userInput)
    fmt.Println(constToSelect) // This string is VK_A
    // But how can i get 5 which is the value of VK_A
}
```

I need this kind of feature because depending on platform, VK_A has different values. For windows, it is 30, for darwin it is 0x00.

Comment: You can't access a constant by name at runtime because constants don't exist at runtime. They're only used at compile time, and replaced inline with the constant value.

Comment: *"depending on platform, VK_A has different values. For windows, it is 30, for darwin it is 0x00."* -- Note that you can use build constraints to manage this, i.e. have two separate files declaring the same constants with different values, one for windows and one for darwin, then, with proper build constraints, the build will include only the windows file when compiling for windows or only the darwin file when compiling for darwin.

Comment: @mkopriva, the package I am using is built that way. It has a function (Keypress) which takes constants as input like Keypress(VK_A), Keypress(VK_B) .. Keypress(VK_Z). In present scenario, I have to setup 26 if else to pass correct contants. I am looking for a way to generate them depending on the letter I have to press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map and do a look up
https://blog.golang.org/maps

```
m = make(map[string]int)
m["VK_A"] = 5
value := m[constToSelect]
```

Maps are not constants

Comment: Note that this is no longer a constant.